# How to include "titlepage" before the Latex Org Mode document?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have a title page that I would like to put before the Org Mode document. Example is below. Right now, I am producing the title page separately and printing it as 2 separate files. It would be nice to have some possibility to include such page within an Org file, before the actual Org Mode output and before the contents.

How?

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\Large Companies Act 2012 \par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large MEMORANDUM AND ARTICLES OF ASSOCIATION \par}
\vspace{2cm}
OF \par
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large COMPANY LIMITED \par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\large May 18th 2017}
\end{center}
\vfill
Drawn by subscriber:\\  
\\
Mr. Rosario Maddox\\
COMPANY LLTD
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can include raw LaTex in an org source file. In this case, just insert

> \begin{titlepage}
>   ...
>   \end{titlepage}

at the top of your document. (Org automatically adds the documentclass and document environment.)

However, as you discovered, org mode will automatically insert the table of contents before any of your content. You need to turn this off. You'll also need to turn off the automatic title that org generates. The following code will do this:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil title:nil
```

[EDIT: in my original answer I had also set author: and date: to nil, which confused org into reinserting the title even after I set title:nil. The solution was not to set author: or date:, just title:]

Following that, you can insert your titlepage environment. If you want a table of contents following the titlepage, and the latex macro `\tableofcontents` where you want it to appear.

Comment: I have tried, yet title page becomes second, not first

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize my personal config was suppressing the insertion of an extra title page by org mode. See my update

Comment: Thank you @tyler, that solution does work very well. First I insert on top the titlepage and later, before the content, I have inserted 
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
to get the common table of contents.

Answer (score 11):

Use the shortcut <kbd><</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to get the LaTeX export

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex

#+END_EXPORT
```

Then introduce the code there

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\Large Companies Act 2012 \par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large MEMORANDUM AND ARTICLES OF ASSOCIATION \par}
\vspace{2cm}
OF \par
\vspace{2cm}
{\Large COMPANY LIMITED \par}
\vspace{2cm}
{\large May 18th 2017}
\end{center}
\vfill
Drawn by subscriber:\\  
\\
Mr. Rosario Maddox\\
COMPANY LLTD
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
#+END_EXPORT
```

Before exporting, turn off the title option (at the beginning of the file)

```
#+option: title:nil toc:nil
```

Comment: The titlepage becomes then second, not first. On first I see Contents, which I wanted to be second.

Comment: @Mr.RosarioMaddox I've corrected the behaviour. Hope it's what you need! Cheers.

Comment: Watch out it's `options` with an "s".